# Error formatting volume with my microsd

Tags: memory, card-reader

```
Error creating file system: helper exited with exit code 1: cannot open /dev/sdb1: Read-only file system
```

This what I get when I try to format my MicroSD. How do I remove the Read-only file system on the mmc with ubuntu , so I can format it?. Thanks.

Comment: Silly question is it locked with the switch at the side?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a bad question to ask here... Was the card used on a Windows 7 phone?

They can make use of the secure aspect of a SecureDigital card.  The phone embeds a password into the card, bonding the two together.  After they are bonded, another phone, camera or PC should not be able to use it - even to format it.

That said, if you have other devices that can read the card, try formatting it there first.  Based on how complete that devices support for the SD device format is, you may be able to format it there, and then reformat it on the PC if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should unmount the device

```
# umount /dev/sdb1
```

and then format it with Gparted. You can install it with

```
# apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: gparted is normally standard installed with ubuntu. Maybe you should explain how to format the microSD with gparted.